# Worklight wlapp won't deploy

Tags: deployment, ibm-mobilefirst

I've tried multiple times with Worklight v5.0.5 to deploy a wlapp applcation to the worklight server. It use to work. However, suddenly whenever I try to reinstall the application, the worklight server shows me an error. It says it cannot deploy due to an "Error". That's all I get in the error message. Where is the log file for worklight server on linux? I can't seem to find that either.

Edit:

There is a bug when running Worklight Server v5.0.5 under WAS v8. Worklight Server thinks the application is not found in the database when deploying. There also are hung threads within websphere. The only way to correct this issue is to completely restart WebSphere. So if you can't deploy and you get a basic "Error" message. Just restart WebSphere. Sorry users, I'll have to shut down the mobile application while I restart WAS. Geez. I expected better.

Comment: Your logs should be here: /opt/IBM/Worklight/server/whatever you named it/usr/servers/worklightServer/logs/

Comment: More information would be helpful. Are you running on WAS? Tomcat? Jetty? If you're running through the Eclipse studio (non production) then your log files will be located at WORKSPACE_HOME/PROJECT_NAME/WorklightServerHome/APP_NAME/log.

Comment: I'm running under WAS v8 on CentOS. This is a QA server.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug within WebSphere that prevents the wlapp from deploying. A restart is required. See the notes above for details.